# Should I use notify() instaed of notifyAll() in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, shared-variable, test-and-set

I was thinking about this code:

```
public class SharedVariable<T> {

    private T value;

    public SharedVariable(T init){ 
        this.value = init;
    }

    public synchronized void testAndSet(Predicate<? super T> p, T value)
         throws InterruptedException{ 

       while (!p.test(this.value)){
           this.wait();
           this.value = value;
       }

       this.notifyAll();

    } 
}
```

Would it be possible to replace `.notifyAll()` with `.notify();`? Could problems arise?

Comment: What is the purpose of this `SharedVariable` class? Can you give an example of how it will be used?

Comment: P.S., `testAndSet` is a strange name for what that method does. Most developers would expect a method with that name to either succeed or fail and return _immediately_ in either case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to manage locks. `notify()` wakes up only one thread chosen by thread scheduler. If you have more than two thread sharing the resource, `notifyAll()` wakes up all of them and one acquires the lock.

Technically, there's no problem if you replace that if the code is simple.